# Listview group works wierdly

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

In my app, I display a `listview` with a few entries. I can group them by groups and it works well.

When I do the same in Excel/MatLab via the API I created (based on the same code) the groups doesn't work, see pictures:

In the application:

[image]

And in the API:

[image]

As you can see, it doesn't work. Here's the code I use:

```
// Sets the ListView to the groups created for the specified column. 
private void SetGroups(Hashtable groups,int column)
{            
    // Remove the current groups.
    listView1.Groups.Clear();

    // Copy the groups for the column to an array.
    ListViewGroup[] groupsArray = new ListViewGroup[groups.Count];
    groups.Values.CopyTo(groupsArray, 0);

    // Sort the groups and add them to the ListView.
    Array.Sort(groupsArray, new ListViewGroupSorter(listView1.Sorting));
    listView1.Groups.AddRange(groupsArray);

    // Iterate through the items in the ListView, assigning each  
    // one to the appropriate group. 
    foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
    {
        // Retrieve the subitem text corresponding to the column. 
        string subItemText = item.SubItems[column].Text;

        // For the Title column, use only the first 3 letters. 
        if (column == 0)
        {
            subItemText = subItemText.Substring(0,3);
        }

        // Assign the item to the matching group.
        item.Group = (ListViewGroup) groups[subItemText];
    }
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: "When I do the same in Excel/MatLab via the API I created (based on the same code) the groups doesn't work"? Is it Excel/Matlab or Windows Forms? Where do you create the one that doesn't work?

Comment: @RezaAghaei since this is the same DLL for both Excel and Matlab, I would say that it's a WinForm. When I use this particular form in my main application it works like a charm but when I try to open it in Excel the groups don't work

Comment: You can tell from the listview styling that this cannot work.  From the MSDN article for LVM_SETGROUPINFO: "To use this message, you must provide a manifest specifying Comclt32.dll version 6.0. For more information on manifests, see Enabling Visual Styles".  This is not necessarily easy to do when you run inside a host app.  A sample Google query is "matlab enable visual styles".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `Application.EnableVisualStyles();` in constructor of form:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
}
```

Comment: Well played. That rocks!